# 404 error when building Git project in TFS2013

Tags: git, tfs, build, build-process

I'm trying to get a git project to build through TFS 2013 Update 4 - Software Version 12.0.31101.0 (Tfs2013.Update4).  We have no issues with building projects under TFSVC with this server, but Git projects are unable to build.

I've setup a build definition (using the default `GitTemplate.12.xaml` template) with the following configurations:

[image: Process Tab]
[image: Source Settings Tab]

This is the log that I get from the build (total time to failure is 1 second):

```
Update build number

Run on agent (reserved build agent Chutzpah Controller)

Initialize environment

Pull sources from Git repo
 Exception Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). (type LibGit2SharpException)
Exception Data Dictionary:
libgit2.code = -1
libgit2.category = 12


Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String repositoryUrl, String workingFolder, Boolean checkoutSubmodules)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at System.Func`4.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitRepositoryBase.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

I've thought that it may be the URL it's hitting, but the URL it generates from the Source Settings tab when you uncheck `Get sources from a Team Foundation Git repository` works just fine:

```
http://teamsource:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Live%20Link%20Dashboard/_git/Live%20Link%20Dashboard
```

So then I thought it was my path to the solution file from the `Build` section of the process template - as such I've tried the following values, none of which work:

```
\LiveLinkDashboard.sln
$\LiveLinkDashboard.sln
/LiveLinkDashboard.sln
$/LiveLinkDashboard.sln
```

I'm at a loss here - does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the ellipsis as the screenshot shows, remove your solution, and add the solution from the workspace. The project path looks like \LiveLinkDashboard\LiveLinkDashboard.sln

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried that multiple times and it just doesn't want to work...I'm not so sure that it's the project path that's the issue, I think it is just having a hard time resolving the url of the git repo?

Comment: Go to Team Explorer--Settings--Repository Settings, and check Remotes to see whether the Remotes looks like http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/teamprojectname. You can also create a new GIT team project and a simple project, push the project into team project and queue a new build, to see whether you'll get the same error.

Comment: While it doesn't fix the issue it is interesting to note that when you run `git remote -v` it returns back a url like 'http://teamsource:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/reponame'...but when you look at the build definition's repo URL it returns back a url like 'http://teamsource:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/teamprojectname/_git/reponame'...I have tried both urls resolve in a web browser to the same endpoint, and the build fails with both as well, but it definitely seems like it could be related to the issue...I'll some more testing later today

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like this one: [TFS 2013 git CI build definition points to incorrect address](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795602/tfs-2013-git-ci-build-definition-points-to-incorrect-address)

And the fix from Microsoft is:

> This issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013. You can install a
>   trial version of Visual Studio 2013 with the fix from:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832436

Comment: I have the latest version of VS2013 already installed - this doesn't resolve the issue for me...I'm also going to bring in my laptop with VS2015 this afternoon to see if maybe that one can recreate the build definition differently

Comment: I've also got a TFS2015 server setup in a lab environment here, I'll give that a go to see if maybe it resolves the issue and if so I'll dig into seeing if we can update our build server

Comment: @RobertPetz Can you try to perform a git clone with "http://teamsource:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/Live%20Link%20Dashboard" on the build server to see if the action can be finished successfully?

Comment: that is an excellent point - I never once tried hitting the repos from the build server itself.  I will give that a try first thing in the morning and report back

Comment: @eddit - MSFT I was able to successfully do a git clone on the build server without issue...doesn't look like that's the fix to this issue =(