# TFS Build Fail when running for TFS-GIT Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am using VS2015 & TFS2013.

I have a GIT repository on TFS which has got a web application and I am trying to publish that using TFS build.

I created a build for deploying that web application which fails.

Here is the full **error message**:

```
Cloning repository 'http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/GitTest/_git/GitTest' into 'C:\Builds\2014\GitTest\TestGitBuild\src'.
**Exception Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).** (type LibGit2SharpException) Exception Data Dictionary: libgit2.code = -1 libgit2.category = 12 Exception Stack Trace: Server stack trace: at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts) at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String repositoryUrl, String workingFolder, Boolean checkoutSubmodules) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase) at System.Func`4.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitRepositoryBase.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result) at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result) at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

[image]

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: If I'd hazard a guess the Notification Url of the TFS server is configured incorrectly.

Comment: what do you mean by notification url of tfs? If you mean the localhost url then I've tried that url on the server which host tfs then this url does resolve to my repository.

Comment: Sure it does, but I suspect that your build server isn't running on that same machine, is it?

Comment: you are right it is running on a different server. we have TFS builds which are working fine but GIT build fail.

Comment: Are you using the default `GitTemplate.12.xaml` template? Could you share your configurations of the build template?

Comment: To determine whether this related  to the URL, the URL it generates from the Source Settings tab, you can try to uncheck *Get sources from a Team Foundation Git repository* and build again.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT when I try Get sources from a Team Foundation Git repository I get this error above mentioned in question, and when I uncheck and give repository url I get this error "You are not authorised to access http://ourtfsservers.co.uk"

Yes I am using GitTemplate.12.xaml default template.

In source settings
Repository URL: http://ourtfsserver.co.uk/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/GitTest

Default branch:
master

Comment: Seems you didn't have access to remote git repo. Could you try to perform a git clone with "xx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/…; on the build server to see if the action can be finished successfully?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT TFS and Build server are on same server. Do I need to install GIT Bash on that server? I am new to git and i know how to do it with VS.

Comment: Yes, you need to install something like this. Just try to make sure you have enough access to connect to remote git repo on your build server to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Had no luck yet. Do you have more insight into this.
Found this article with exactly same problem but no result(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091489/404-error-when-building-git-project-in-tfs2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "Project Collection Build Services Accounts" and giving Read permissions solved the problem for me.

You can go to this popup by right clicking on your project and then select Security in your Web portal.

[image]