# VSO Build failed with submodules

Tags: git, tfs

We are using TFS 2015 and getting an error when we try to build our repository. We have two TeamProjects, in A is the main repository we want to build, in B are submodules that are referenced in A.

The build fails with the following message:

```
2017-05-17T14:16:37.9148422Z Checked out branch refs/heads/develop for repository A at commit 8bece3e87781f4064c61ff8ce750f6dbd17bca02
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_submodule_update(SubmoduleHandle submodule, Boolean init, GitSubmoduleOptions& options)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei LibGit2Sharp.SubmoduleCollection.Update(String name, SubmoduleUpdateOptions options)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.DoUpdateSubmodules(Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, Int32 currentRecursionDepth, String username, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.UpdateSubmodules(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2017-05-17T14:16:39.2898443Z ##[error]   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
```

The user that executes the build has the rights to read all needed repositories, what else could be the problem?

.gitmodules of A

```
[submodule "custom/plugins/B"]
    path = custom/plugins/B
    url = https://tfs/Root/Project/_git/B
```

The log when triggering a build.

```
******************************************************************************
Wird gestartet: Quellen abrufen
******************************************************************************
Syncing repository: shopware (Git)
Klonen wird gestartet
ee22f3ff7951b579e57b8d9b65f14d6c382ca25a bis C:\Webteam-Agent\_work\9\s mit Submodulen ausgecheckt
revparsing ee22f3ff7951b579e57b8d9b65f14d6c382ca25a
grabbed ref , obj ee22f3ff7951b579e57b8d9b65f14d6c382ca25a
dereferenced to commit ee22f3ff7951b579e57b8d9b65f14d6c382ca25a
Checked out branch refs/heads/develop for repository shopware at commit ee22f3ff7951b579e57b8d9b65f14d6c382ca25a
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_submodule_update(SubmoduleHandle submodule, Boolean init, GitSubmoduleOptions& options)
bei LibGit2Sharp.SubmoduleCollection.Update(String name, SubmoduleUpdateOptions options)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.DoUpdateSubmodules(Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, Int32 currentRecursionDepth, String username, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.UpdateSubmodules(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.AgentExecutionTerminationException: Fehler beim Vorbereiten des Repositorys mit einer Ausnahme. ---> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_submodule_update(SubmoduleHandle submodule, Boolean init, GitSubmoduleOptions& options)
bei LibGit2Sharp.SubmoduleCollection.Update(String name, SubmoduleUpdateOptions options)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.DoUpdateSubmodules(Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, Int32 currentRecursionDepth, String username, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.UpdateSubmodules(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, Repository repository, Int32 maxRecursionDepth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Der Worker Worker-b7f0b104-abc3-4af8-a305-6a3e93d9a72e hat die Ausführung des Auftrags b7f0b104-abc3-4af8-a305-6a3e93d9a72e abgeschlossen.
******************************************************************************
Build wird abgeschlossen
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Is your submodule correctly pointing to the repo in the other team project? Storing dependencies across team project boundaries is a bad idea.

Comment: I added the configuration, why is it a bad idea to store repos across team projects?

Comment: @Knerd Could you please post more logs about your Get Source step and test if this issue happens in other build definitions? Try to test in other repository

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT it works, as long as all repositories are in the same TeamProject, if it is a different TeamProject ist fails.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT I added more logs, the Visual Studio version installed is 2015 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add "Project Collection Build Services Accounts" and giving Read and other permissions of this Git repository.

For more details, refer to this thread: [TFS Build Fail when running for TFS-GIT Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112023/tfs-build-fail-when-running-for-tfs-git-repository)

Also make sure you install Visual Studio 2013 and higher version on your build agent.

**Update:**

I have reproduce your issues and this issue is caused by the Url is not correct. 
Please login TFS from TFS web site, find the .gitmodules in team project A. Then check if Url(`url = https://tfs/Root/Project/_git/B`) is correct. Make sure it could be connected in your build server.

Then in the build definition, set Clean repository to **True** and build again.

Comment: They have the read permissions, the application is PHP based so why would I need VS2013?

Comment: @Knerd It is mentioned in this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795602/tfs-2013-git-ci-build-definition-points-to-incorrect-address.

Comment: @Tingting09029-MSFT: It fails during get source step.

Comment: When I clone the repository with the commandline it works without any issue.

Comment: With the agent user, yes.

Comment: @Knerd make sure you are choosing the correct branch.  Please check the .gitmodules file under the C:\Webteam-Agent\_work\...\s path, if the path in it correct?

Comment: I checked the .gitmodules and it is fine, might it be that the unix file endings cause problems?

Comment: The code has \n as line ending. We fixed it now by using the most recent build agent.

Comment: @Knerd Could you please post it as the answer for this issue and make it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution for this specific issue, so I upgraded to the most recent version of the VSTS agent and with that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend installing git bash and running `git submodule update` in your build directory.  You'll get a much more searchable error from git bash than you will from VSO.

Another thing to try in git bash is to go to the submodule directory and run `git remote -v` It should show you the URL it's using.  If it's out of sync with `.gitmodules` in the main repo, then run `git submodule sync` to update it.

Once you figure out how to fix it with git, you'll probably be better equipped to trick the Microsoft stuff into working.  Then file a bug report with them.